# How to improve performance of "minus" query on JSONB field in big table?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb, postgresql-performance

In a PostgreSQL 12.7 database I have table with a JSONB field. Table has million rows. `table1` is like:

```
id    | value
--    | --------------------------------------
1     | {"1001": "coke", "1002": "soda"}
2     | {"2001": "fanta", "1001": "coke"}
3     | {"3001": "beer", "2001": "fanta"}
```

Whenever, I need to remove items 1001, I have query like:

**Query 1:**

```
UPDATE table1 set value = value - '1001'
```

**Query 2:**

```
UPDATE table1 set value = value - '1001' WHERE value ? '1001'
```

Query 2 takes about 2 seconds and Query 1 takes around 20 seconds. I am looking way improve update speed somewhere quarter of seconds.

Comment: The syntax is invalid for `jsonb`, your "Query 2' is nonsense. Please present a consistent question, and a meaningful description. And always declare your version of Postgres.

Comment: Sample values are still invalid (wrong quotes). And query 2 still does not work. The operator `?` only works for top-level keys, but your sample values are wrapped in a JSON array. Please provide information as instructed here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: Thank you. I edited sample value. Thank you for helping to clear out garbages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support query 2 with an index. Like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON table1 USING gin (value);
```

The [default GIN operator class for `jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) supports the `?` operator.

While only ***few*** rows are affected, that should be *very* effective. If a major percentage of all rows is changed, indexes cannot help (would actually add cost).

Comment: I am testing with this solution...

Comment: This solution worked for me with query2. As, update was perform on few thousands rows. However upsert has ben slow - 70k rows (insert/update) takes 164 sec. May be I will start different thread.

Comment: @KrishnaSunuwar: 70k ~ 7 % for 1 million rows. The index already falls off with that kind of cardinality, especially for writes. Yes, start a new question for the UPSERT. Remember to include relevant details as advised.